# How to load data async from firebase and display it in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I try to display the usernames of users that the logged in user is following. In detail only those, who also have a story (like Snapchat) in a simple UICollectionView. 
So I need the username of that person displayed as a simple Label in that cell. 
To get that, I thought that I could simply add all those with a story to an Array and later on get the first item for the first story, second item for the second story and so on...
But as I mentioned before I would like to retrieve and display the username. The problem now is that the "cellForItemAt" function is not waiting for the Array to be filled up by the data retrieved from firebase, so it uses the empty `self.storyNames` array and with that also the `return self.storyNames.count` is equal to 0.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView_stories: UICollectionView!

    var storyNames: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView_stories.delegate = self
        collectionView_stories.dataSource = self
        collectionView_stories.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

        getStoryNames() { storyNames in
            self.storyNames = storyNames
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView_stories.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func barButton_camera_pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func barButton_inbox_pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.storyNames.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let story_cell = collectionView_stories.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stories_cell", for: indexPath) as? StoryCollectionViewCell

        story_cell?.imageView_story.layer.cornerRadius = (story_cell?.imageView_story.frame.size.width)! / 2
        story_cell?.imageView_story.clipsToBounds = true
        story_cell?.imageView_story.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        story_cell?.imageView_story.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        story_cell?.imageView_story.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        story_cell?.imageView_story.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        story_cell?.imageView_story.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        story_cell?.imageView_story.image = UIImage(named: "bitmoji")

        story_cell?.label_username.text = self.storyNames[indexPath.row]

        return story_cell!
    }

    func getStoryNames(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
        var tempStoryNames: [String] = []
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("subscriptions").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let dict = child.value as! String
                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(dict).child("hasStory").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                    if let item = snapshot.value as? Bool {
                        if (item == true) {
                            dispatchGroup.enter()
                            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(dict).child("username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                                let aaa = snapshot.value as! String
                                tempStoryNames.append(aaa)
                                print(tempStoryNames)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                completion(tempStoryNames)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? I did my best and also know that this is not the best code, but I am working on it and therefore I really need your help. I appreciate every single answer!

Comment: Are you able to see tempStoryNames? If you put a breakpoint at numberOfItemsInSection, what is storyCounter, what is storyNames? Continue. Again, what is storyCounter, what is storyNames? You can po storyCounter in the lldb debug section.

Comment: @Mocha Basically the array is created all correctly, meaning that the self.storyNames array after completion kind of looks like this ["firstName", "secondName"]. The only problem is that the "func cellForItemAt" is not waiting on the retrieving to be finished, so it takes the empty self.storyNames array.

Answer (score 0):

in `numberOfItemsInSection` You should depend on the storyNames length, that would make sure that your data will be displayed correctly

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.storyNames.count
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is quite an easy solution for making my code less complicated. But what exactly is the problem now (exact problem stated in comments section)?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense how you **know** your cellForItemAt method has an empty storyNames array because if your storyNames.count is 0, the cellForItemAt method will never be reached. CellForItemAt only gets called when there are more than one items in that section.

Can you put a breakpoint in the completion handler to see if you are getting back the correct storyNames?

```
    getStoryNames() { storyNames in
        self.storyNames = storyNames // breakpoint here to see if actual data
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView_stories.reloadData() // breakpoint here to see if storyNames still empty
        }
    }
```

If your cellForItemAt method does get called, then I think you should debug that method. You never register your stories_cell identifier so maybe that could be it?